# Get an jmeter Error Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm using JMeter version 5.11. My test plan has one thread group.

I want to run the load test with 100 thread groups, Always gives following error any other suggestions to overcome this?

Run following  command in jmeter bin folder

```
sh jmeter -n -t "path to .jmx file" -l "path to output csv file" -e -o "path to output folder"
```

Then gives

```
Created the tree successfully for jmx
Starting the test @ Mon ...

Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
```

Note - Already added  HTTP Request Defaults and set timeout periods(milliseconds) to Connect and response timeouts as 10000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump`

This is a [normal message](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/81ba16c2213c6af78a388a7c94a11474d20348a6/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/JMeter.java#L1442) when test is in progress

So you just need to wait until test is over